# Razor Pages SelectList Won't Populate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

My Branch SelectList won't populate with data.
The query does return 15 records, but they are not binding to the Select control.
Any thoughts?

This is what appears in the HTML page results for asp-items, instead of the  items. Why does this get added tp asp-items? **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]**

```
<select asp-items="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]"
asp-for="Branch"></select>
```

Here is my HTML Razor Page.

```
  <h5 class="card-title">Choose Branch</h5>
  <select id="selectBranches" asp-for="Branch" asp-items="@Model.Branches" disabled="enabled" class="custom-select"></select>
```

Here is my C# RazorPage.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using SetpointIS.Models;
using SetpointIS.Models.Datawarehouse;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
public class EditModel : PageModel
     {
            private DBContextVuPoint db;

            public List<SelectListItem> Branches { get; set; }

            public EditModel(DBContextVuPoint _db)
            {
                db = _db;
            }

            public void OnGet()
            {
                Branches = db.Branch.Select(a =>
                        new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = a.BranchId.ToString(),
                            Text = "(" + a.Abbreviation + ")" + a.Name
                        }).ToList();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `asp-for` you wrote `Branch` instead of 'Branches'